# Weird error message when implementing IEquatable

Tags: vb.net, overriding, shadow, equals-operator

```
Class gridTradingState
    Implements IEquatable(Of gridTradingState)


    Public Overrides Function Equals(other As gridTradingState) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of gridTradingState).Equals
        '    Throw New NotImplementedException()

        Return True
    End Function
    ...


End Class
```

That's a very simple function right?

Well, I got this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error BC30284 function 'Equals' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because
> it does not override a function in a base
> class.    nicehash2   C:\Users\whatever\Dropbox\vb.net\gridtrading.vb 10  Active

Okay. So I cannot declare Equals as overrides because it does not override a function in a base class.

What is the base class? Who knows. But given that gridTradingState doesn't inherit anything I presume it must be Object class

So I remove the keyword overrides

and I got

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning BC40005 function 'Equals' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'Object'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'.  nicehash2   C:\Users\teguh\Dropbox\vb.net\gridtrading.vb    10  Active
```

I can add the keyword shadow to get the error away. But it feels weird.

If my base class have and overideable function called Equals why I get the first warning and if my base class does not have Equals why do I get the second warning.

Either must be true right?

Now a good answer will be very detailed and also mention related issues.

What base class are they talking about? Object?

What function do they think I am overriding or shadowing?

What is the proper way to implement Equals anyway.

I've heard I should also implement getHash or something. However, IEquatable truly doesn't have anything else. Why?

I am not trying to ask several questions at once. More like I want detailed answer of why I got this silly errors/warnings

```
namespace System
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Defines a generalized method that a value type or class implements to create
    //     a type-specific method for determining equality of instances.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The type of objects to compare.
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public interface IEquatable<T>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   other:
        //     An object to compare with this object.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the current object is equal to the other parameter; otherwise, false.
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        bool Equals(T other);
    }
}
```

To further investigate this issue, I add a line

```
Dim b = MyBase.Equals(other)
```

Right clicking MyBase confirms my suspicion that MyBase is simply Object.

So I look at the code and this is what I see

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   obj:
    //     The object to compare with the current object.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the specified object is equal to the current object; otherwise, false.
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public virtual bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.Equals(this, obj);
    }
```

I use https://icsharpcode.github.io/CodeConverter/

And I get the vb.net version.

and the vb.net version of that code is a bit like

```
Public Overridable Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return RuntimeHelpers.Equals(Me, obj)
End Function

'
' Summary:
'     Determines whether the specified object instances are considered equal.
'
' Parameters:
'   objA:
'     The first object to compare.
'
'   objB:
'     The second object to compare.
'
' Returns:
'     true if the objects are considered equal; otherwise, false. If both objA and
'     objB are null, the method returns true.
<__DynamicallyInvokable>
Public Shared Function Equals(ByVal objA As Object, ByVal objB As Object) As Boolean
    If objA Is objB Then
        Return True
    End If

    If objA Is Nothing OrElse objB Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If

    Return objA.Equals(objB)
End Function
```

So Class Object does have an overridable function called Equals

So why do I get the second warning?

My guess is because my Equals function took another gridTradingState object and not another Object object. But that's what I want right?

So where do I went wrong?

Comment: *"What is the base class? Who knows."*. Um, everyone knows. It's `Object`. `Object` is the root for the entire .NET inheritance tree. Any type without an explicit base type inherits `Object` directly.

Comment: *"Either must be true right?"*. No. Neither is right. You're overloading the `Equals` method, because your type now has multiple `Equals` methods with different signatures, but you don't have explicitly specify that you're overloading in that context. You only need to override or shadow if your method has the same name AND signature as an existing method in the base type. If that method is declared `Overridable` (`virtual` in C#) then you can override it, otherwise you need to shadow it. You don't need to - fact can't do - either in this case because there's no such base method.

Comment: So what exactly should I do?

Comment: OT: You really ought to name all types starting with an upper-case letter, just as is done throughout .NET itself and every third=party library I've ever encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the `Overrides` keyword and you're done. Your type inherits `Object` because you're not specifying any other base type explicitly. `Object` has no `Equals` method with that signature so there's nothing to override or shadow. You're overloading the `Equals` method, i.e. there are multiple implementations with different signatures, but you don't need to specify that explicitly when the overloads are in different types.

EDIT:

I tell a lie. You are overloading and you do need the `Overloads` keyword in order to avoid the warning you describe:

```vb
Public Overloads Function Equals(other As gridTradingState) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of gridTradingState).Equals
```

Comment: I do that and I get this warning: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning BC40005 function 'Equals' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'Object'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'. nicehash2 C:\Users\teguh\Dropbox\vb.net\gridtrading.vb 10 Active

Comment: Of course, getting rid the overrides method is the first thing I did. Yet I get warning.

Comment: @user4951, I have updated my answer. You do need to explicitly overload to avoid that warning.

Comment: Ah overloads. Overrides and shadow. I got to look that up again. A bit confusing.

Comment: @user4951, not really confusing. Overloading is multiple members in the same type, inherited or not, with same name but different signatures. The other two are a member in a type with the same name and signature as a member in the base type. Overriding is generally preferable and pretty much always done if the base member is `Overridable` (`virtual` in C#), otherwise you use `Shadows` (`new` in C#). When invoking a member, overridden members respect the type of the object while shadowed members respect the type of the reference.